# Concatenating strings and variables in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, string-concatenation

I would like to create a dynamic file path in `.bat` file. At the moment the file path looks like this:

```
"C:\FolderA\FolderB\FileA.xlsx"
```

I would like to incorporate today's date in the file name to produce something like that:

```
/exp:"C:\FolderA\FolderB\FileA " & date() & ".xlsx" /T`
```

I have tried creating a variable and concatenating it with the hard coded part but it does not work:

```
set Mydate=!date:~10,4!!date:~7,2!!date:~4,2!
/exp:"C:\FolderA\FolderB\FileA "&%Mydate%&".xlsx" /T
```

What are the rules on concatenating characters and variables and on quotation marks in batch?
How to debug in batch using Notepad?

Comment: Why are you using DOS?

Comment: I think you mean Windows Command Prompt (cmd.exe) rather than MS-DOS. You can't have file name extensions > 3 letters in MS-DOS so you could not create a file called something.xlsx for instance.

Comment: @Radmation: Because there is no alternative to it here

Comment: @Jack Hughes: I have edited my post. We are taking .bat

Comment: You may find the question answered more quickly on the Super User or Server Fault forums.

Comment: **MS-DOS** is an OS from the 1980s; I assume you are working with **Windows** command prompt (`cmd.exe` since Windows NT)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

?

```
/exp:"C:\FolderA\FolderB\FileA "&%Mydate%&".xlsx" /T
```

?

This is not `cmd` syntax. To set a variable, use the `set` command. Also to concatenate, you don't have (read: must not) use something like concatenation symbols:

```
set "var=C:\FolderA\FolderB\FileA %Mydate%.xlsx"
```

(whatever `/exp:` or `/t` is supposed to do - it does not work in `cmd`)

To rename a file, use `ren` (or the long form `rename`). To get help to a command use `command /?` e.g. `rename /?`

Comment: Thank you for your post, I did not know these rules (no use of concatenation symbols, quotation marks...) I am still interested in how to debug such script (run line by line).

Comment: `batch` is very basic. Debugging is basically done manually with `echo` and `pause`

Comment: [here](http://ss64.com/nt/) is an overview with possible `cmd` commands (a few of them don't work on all windows versions) including a good description of usage and syntax. If you are new to it, consider learning powershell instead (native to current windows versions). It's much more powerful and has a designed consistent syntax. If you decide to stay with batch - welcome to the land of headache (well - one gets used to it...).

Answer (score 0):

```
for /f "tokens=1-7 delims=/: " %%a in ("%date% %time%") do (

set idow=%%a
set imonth=%%b
set idate=%%c
set iyear=%%d
set ihour=%%e
set imin=%%f
set isec=%%g

set vDate=%%d-%%b-%%c-%%e-%%f

)
cd /d "%log_dir%"
rename %prefix%.log %prefix%-%vDate%.log
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).